# How to make a stellar project using the Django framework?

Tags: stellar-sdk, python-sdk

I have been tasked to develop a stellar platform and want to develop it in Django, but I have not found any documentation or specification in Django. Here are my requirements:

Register/Login

input email and you get verified by email, then the website will generate Public/Secret Key for your account -> Login by secret key(without account)

Exchange : List assets fetched from horizon API

Search button to look after "asset code or home domain"

If you click on asset: Show info about it, price,24h change, volume, graph, trade pairs, order book, Trades/Holders The possibility to create trust line between your account and that asset so you can buy/sell it / place orders. Account Section: View your balance, total assets Make payments

I am just confused about the login/registration process via stellar API. I do not know how to do it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Python SDK](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base)?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I am confused how to use it for Django accounts like login/signup to stellar api.